# Runtime CPU type detection for Android on ARM

Tags: android, android-ndk, arm, neon

What is the simplest method to determine CPU type from within a running C application? I am interested in determining how many cores current CPU has and whether it has a NEON unit. One simple solution could be to check cpuinfo flags in /proc but I am not sure if it's a fast and reliable method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check neon support using [this doc](http://www.kandroid.org/ndk/docs/CPU-ARM-NEON.html). To get core count read [this thread](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26490) and take a look at [this page](http://www.kandroid.org/ndk/docs/CPU-FEATURES.html).

Comment: The bottom line is: yes, checking cpuinfo flags in /proc is fast and reliable.

Comment: Android now recommend using the [cpufeatures library](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpu-features) (emphasis *now*). You should not parse `/proc` or `cpuinfo`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Yeppp! library](http://www.yeppp.info) to get a lot of information about CPU. This information is also accessible via Java bindings, so you could define several native methods in your classes, e.g. `processGeneric()` and `processNeon()`, and call the NEON method only if the CPU supports it:

```
import info.yeppp.Library;
import info.yeppp.ArmCpuSimdFeature;
import info.yeppp.CpuMicroarchitecture;

if (Library.isSupported(ArmCpuSimdFeature.NEON)) {
    if (Library.getMicroarchitecture().equals(CpuMicroarchitecture.Krait)) {
        /* Special NEON implementation for recent Qualcomm processors */
        nativeClass.processKrait();
    } else {
        /* Generic NEON implementation */
        nativeClass.processNeon();
    }
} else {
    /* Generic implementation without NEON */
    nativeClass.processGeneric();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Build.SUPPORTED_ABIS` to check CPU Abi version(eg,arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a, etc.).

And also, to check is neon supported, using the `/proc/cpuinfo` file.

### ABI

Sample Code

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static List<String> getSupportedABIs() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        return Arrays.asList(Build.SUPPORTED_ABIS);
    } else {
        return Arrays.asList(Build.CPU_ABI, Build.CPU_ABI2);
    }
}
```

sample out put is:

```
|    device     |   arch     |         Abi list
| Moto Nexus 6  | arm 32bit  | [armeabi-v7a, armeabi]
| Huawei Mate 8 | arm 64bit  | [arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a, armeabi]
| OPPO R7s      | arm 64 bit | [arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a, armeabi]
| Moto X Style  | arm 64 bit | [arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a, armeabi]
```

### NEON

Here is a sample output of 'cat /proc/cpuinfo'

```
shell@mako:/ $ cat /proc/cpuinfo
Processor   : ARMv7 Processor rev 2 (v7l)
processor   : 0
BogoMIPS    : 13.53

processor   : 1
BogoMIPS    : 13.53

processor   : 2
BogoMIPS    : 13.53

processor   : 3
BogoMIPS    : 13.53

Features    : swp half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt
CPU implementer : 0x51
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0x06f
CPU revision    : 2

Hardware    : QCT APQ8064 MAKO
Revision    : 000b
Serial      : 0000000000000000
```

Take care about the `Features` line. It contains all features the CPU supported. Note: the `neon` feature is listed.

So the very easy way to check if current device support `neon`, you just create a `InputStreamReader("/proc/cpuinfo")`, and read the `Features` line.

### BTW

Those method described above try to avoid using native lib.
If you want more detailed info about the cpu, try the official NDK library [cpufeatures](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpu-features.html). And there is a [ndk-sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/blob/master/hello-neon/app/src/main/cpp/helloneon.c).

Answer (score -1):

Since you have the NDK tag here's a C context answer. When using modern NDKs I believe you are expected to use Android's [cpu-features library](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpu-features).

Copy `cpu-features.h` and `cpu-features.c` from `$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/sources/android/cpufeatures` to your project source tree. Compile it as part of your sources.

Then...

---

> ... determine CPU type from within a running C application?

To test whether the CPU is ARMv7 perform the following. The Android docs state to test the family first with `android_getCpuFamily()`.

```
bool IsARMv7()
{
#if defined(__ANDROID__) && (defined(__aarch64__) || defined(__arm__))
    if (((android_getCpuFamily() & ANDROID_CPU_FAMILY_ARM) != 0) &&
        ((android_getCpuFeatures() & ANDROID_CPU_ARM_FEATURE_ARMv7) != 0))
            return true;
#endif
    return false;
}
```

---

> ... how many cores current CPU has and whether it has a NEON unit

To test for NEON use the following code. NEON is called ASIMD on ARMv8/Aarch64.

```
bool HasNEON()
{
#if defined(__ANDROID__) && defined(__aarch64__)
    if (((android_getCpuFamily() & ANDROID_CPU_FAMILY_ARM64) != 0) &&
        ((android_getCpuFeatures() & ANDROID_CPU_ARM64_FEATURE_ASIMD) != 0))
            return true;
#elif defined(__ANDROID__) && defined(__arm__)
    if (((android_getCpuFamily() & ANDROID_CPU_FAMILY_ARM) != 0) &&
        ((android_getCpuFeatures() & ANDROID_CPU_ARM_FEATURE_NEON) != 0))
            return true;
#endif
     return false;
}
```

According to the [cpu-features library](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpu-features) docs you use the following for CPU core count. I have never used it, though.

```
int  android_getCpuCount(void);
```